# Is the Gate-Controlled Diode an instance of a trancitor?

Tags: active-components, gyrator, trancitor

I'm not sure it entirely counts. It certainly isn't useful in the way that the current-controlled voltage source is useful as the [original transcitor paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.05842) describes, but more importantly, I am unsure how much its voltage output depends on current characteristics.

The [gate-controlled diode](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228790024_Gate-Controlled_Diode-A_New_Way_for_Electronic_Circuits) is essentially an ordinary diode, but with a MOS gate fabricated on top of it. The electric field present on the MOS gate can increase the width of the depletion region, thereby controlling the breakdown voltage. I thought that this would make it a voltage-controlled voltage source (VCVS) in the same way that a MOSFET can be configured as a voltage-controlled current source (VCCS). But on the other hand, the configuration of the current-controlled voltage source transcitor in the original transcitor article appears to be able to develop voltage without needing a specific loading. (Then again, the hall-effect device described in the original paper appears to be a (passive, albeit nonreciprocal) hall-effect gyrator serving to convert current into voltage.)

Comment: Be careful with your language. It is not true that a MOSFET can be **configured** as a "voltage-controlled current source" because it can not **source** current by itself. In some circuits the MOSFET can be **modeled** as a voltage-controlled current source, but that model is only useful in certain situations. It's a big difference.

Comment: @Elliot -- "mosfet as VCCS" is the high level paradigm by the first paper that is referenced in the question, in its Figure 1 introducing their objectives

Comment: The I-V curves look different.  Doesn't that mean they are not the same?

Comment: @PeteW I take your point, but I wasn't particularly impressed with the paper either.